# Using Laravel 5.6 Blade to send PHP array as JSON string or JSON Object to JS Frontend

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

> I am struggling with trying to identify the best approach for sending the PHP array as JSON
>   string or JSON Object to frontend JavaScript using Laravel 5.6 Blade
>   template.

It seems like when I do the following in Blade template file it never convert it to string.

```
 @php $vueModel = [ ...] @endPhp

  <script>
      sessionStorage.setItem('vueModel', {!! json_encode($vueModel) !!} );
      ...
  </script>
```

It shows as an **[Object Object]** in the Chrome dev tools.

So after this if I try to do the following it will not work (there will be errors):

```
 let model = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('vueModel'));
```

But if I do the following trick, then it spit out the string.

> Please notice the single quote surrounding  '{!! ... !!}'

```
<script>
  sessionStorage.setItem('vueModel', '{!! json_encode($vueModel) !!}' );
  ...
```

However, this has its own problem because now I get the string with backslash encoded quotes and then I will have to fix that.

> So what is the clean way to send the PHP array as a either JSON Object
>   or JSON String without any encoding to Frontend JavaScript using laravel 5.6 Blade template language ? What is
>   the recommended approach in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way that appears to be recommended approach by Laravel 5.6 Blade engine:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('vueModel', JSON.stringify(@json($vueModel)));
```

> Useing **@json** blade directive is a nice and convenient way for converting the PHP
>   Array to JSON Object for Frontend.

Then basically to avoid the encoding issue... on front end you do the following:

> let vModel = JSON.parse( ...your JSON string representation of the PHP
>   Array)!

So this way you get a clean JSON Object on JS frontend without worrying about the encoding issue.